# Website works on localhost, when uploaded does not display images

Tags: html, css

I have a website that works correctly on my computer but when uploaded to the server there are several links that are no appearing. When I check these links through developer tools and it says 'Natural 1 X 1' when the image size is actually 192 X 122 pixels. The images are uploaded and appear on the server.Here is how the link looks:

```
<img src="img/ads/Christie_Lamb_WJO_Advertisement_TN.jpg"/>
```

I have other links with other folders that work fine, such as:

```
<img src="img/website_tn/Murray_Raine_Puppets_Website_TN.jpg">
```

and the offending website page online:
http://elementalarts.com.au/posters.html

Any help appreciated

Comment: Check console it says failed to load resources. Check your link is correct or try adding ./ or ~/

Comment: Everything looks fine when I load your webpage. Maybe you fixed it already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because of adblock, avoid any folders with the name ad/advert when uploading images.

Tried to disable adblock on your page which solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Adblock or any other advertisement blocker?

Adblock sometimes blocks images that come from a folder called `ads` or others similar to that.

When i turn my Adblock off, i can see your images.